# httppost to asp net handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wish to pass a object data to a asp.net handler from aspx.cs and it will cross over another project. Any comment is appreciated.

```
//Project A  (abc.aspx.cs)
      try
      {
          String ltq_str = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ltq);

          int t = -1;
          String result = Gnuse.HTTPSend("http://localhost/is/TQueueDtcsController/integrationservice?tQueueDtcslist", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ltq_str), ref t, "GET");


          if (!result.Equals("success"))
          {
              GRN.delete(Convert.ToInt32(hfId.Value), false);
              lblError.Text = "Inventory integration failed: " + result;
          }

      }
```

For Project B  (TQueueDtcsController.cs)

```
public ActionResult integrationservice(String tQueueDtcslist)
{
        try
        {
            List<TQueueDtcIntegration> ListOftQueueDtc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TQueueDtcIntegration>>(tQueueDtcslist);

           // String[] value_arr = tQueueDtc.ProductName.Split(new char[] { '-' });
            if (ListOftQueueDtc.Count() <=0)
            { return Content("list is empty", "application/text"); }

            foreach (TQueueDtcIntegration tQueueDtcint in ListOftQueueDtc)
            {
               //performed some thing
            }
 }
```

Comment: handlers are specific to extensions. ASP.NET already has one registered for `.aspx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even this is my question but after my friend help me solve the problem, i provide that solution for this question hope can help someone.

```
    try
        {
            String ltq_str = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ltq);
            int t = -1;
            String result = Gnuse.HTTPSend("http://localhost/is/TQueueDtcs/integrationservice?tQueueDtcslist=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ltq_str), ref t, "GET");

            if (!result.Equals("success"))
            {
                GRN.delete(Convert.ToInt32(hfId.Value), false);
                lblError.Text = "Inventory integration failed: " + result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.Message.ToString();
        }
```

The 1st changes : TQueueDtcsController >> TQueueDtcs because cannot directly point to the exactly .cs file which contain that function but it should point to the page which using this function.

The 2nd changes : add the ‘=’ for passing a object or value.